# How to access application internal storage from html file in Assets folder Xamarin.android?

Tags: html, xamarin.android, android-webview, autodesk-forge, android-internal-storage

I have to load a `.svf` file into my `WebView`. I have a `HTML` file in my `Assets` folder and the `.svf` file and all the related files also included in the same folder. I am loading my `.svf` file ussing a `Javascript` code inside `HTML` file and this works without any issue. Following is my `Javascript` code snippet to load the `.svf` file.

```
<script>
const MODEL_URL = './Models/Model1/output.svf';
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'Local' }, async function () {
            const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'));
            viewer.start(MODEL_URL);
        }); 
</script>
```

And I load the html page to the `Webview`as
`wbMain.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");`

Then I moved my `.svf` files into Application Internal storage.`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.MyTestApp/files/Models/output.svf`
and changed `HTML` code `MODEL_URL` like this.
`const MODEL_URL = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.MyTestApp/files/Models/output.svf';`

But now the file is not loading. My `HTML` file is still insidethe `Assets` folder. How can I achieve this? I need to load those files from the internal storage through the javascript code in html file.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

My `WebView` has following file access permissions.

```
wbMain.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
wbMain.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
wbMain.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
```

Comment: Allow the webview client to load from local storage.

Comment: @blackapps I have given the permission but still it same. Please check my UPDATE 1

Comment: Your file does not exist on that path. It should work. It works too with "file://" removed from url.

Comment: File exists. I can see it under my folder in app's internal storage

Comment: What is 'my folder',? Better use File.exists() before starting the Webview.

Comment: storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.MyTestApp/files/Models/

Comment: Which app did you use to see 'my folder'?

Comment: "My Files" on Android 8.0. It is a samsung Inbuilt app I think

Comment: Try with an img tag in html source with src in same folder.

Comment: with img src it works in the same folder. I tried copying an image into the same location. In my case it is not just an image. A 3D model that need to be loaded into a viewer. So cannot simply give as img src.

Comment: If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?